# R-library does not exist

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, r-library

I am trying to load packages in Rstdio. When I use the `command line to load packages "R -e "library('XXXXX')"`, or Run the command `library(XXXXX) in Rstdio console`, I am able to load the package.

But when I try to run a .R file that laods the same package from a .sh file, I get the following error

```
Error in library("XXXXX") : there is no package called ‘XXXXXX’
```

I am running the code in an EC2 instance

Can anyone please help with the error

Comment: Rstdio - is this a typo?

Comment: If you run `which R` is that path different if you run `R.home("bin")` in the same R file where you try to run the `library()` call? How are you executing the .R file? What exactly do the commands look like? Are you using package managers like `renv`?

Comment: Check what paths R knows by running `print(.libPaths())` in both Rstudio and outside.  They will differ--which is your problem.  Check with your local admin (you?) of why that may be, there are many possibly config files that can affect this.

Comment: I tried print(.libpaths()) and the libpaths are different. To correct it I used libpaths(c('xxxx','yyyy',...)) which adds all the libpaths excluding a specific one. What is the posssible reason for this ?